# mypy complains about duplicate module even though its a different module with the same name but a different folder/namespace

Tags: python, mypy

Mypy keeps complaining about duplicate module even though there is no duplicate module but modules with the same name in different folders.

Example tree:

```
.
├── catalog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── k8s_pvc
│       ├── implementation.py
│       └── integration.py
├── executor
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── argo
│   │   ├── implementation.py
│   │   └── integration.py
│   └── k8s_job
│       ├── implementation.py
│       └── integration.py
├── experiment_tracker
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mlflow
│       └── implementation.py
├── run_log_store
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── chunked_k8s_pvc
│   │   ├── implementation.py
│   │   └── integration.py
│   └── k8s_pvc
│       ├── implementation.py
│       └── integration.py
└── secrets
```

MyPy error:

```
magnus/extensions/executor/argo/implementation.py: error: Duplicate module named "implementation" (also at "magnus/extensions/catalog/k8s_pvc/implementation.py")
magnus/extensions/executor/argo/implementation.py: note: Are you missing an __init__.py? Alternatively, consider using --exclude to avoid checking one of them.
```

My mypy config:

```
[mypy]
implicit_optional = True
ignore_missing_imports = True
plugins = pydantic.mypy
show_error_codes = True

follow_imports = silent
warn_redundant_casts = True
warn_unused_ignores = True
check_untyped_defs = True
implicit_reexport = True
```

Can we not use the same name in different packages and satisfy mypy?

Cheers,

Comment: Are you missing an `__init__.py`?

Comment: Do you mean every package should have an ```--init__.py``` ? I can try but python3 removed that dependency for package recognition.

Comment: That actually worked!! Thanks @STerliakov .. Any reasons why it does not work with __init__.py?